# Editing 2 things on the page at once

Tags: bug, mathjax

I tried to edit the question and an answer on a page on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Step 1: I clicked on "edit" on an answer. (Which edits the answer on the same page.)

Step 2: I clicked on "edit" on the question. (Which edits the question on the same page.)

Step 3: I edited the answer slightly (like adding a space and removing it afterwards).

Step 4: The MathJax of the answer is not rendered properly.

When the question edit is cancelled, the behaviour returns to normal (MathJax renders correctly.)

Is this known behaviour or is this a bug?

Comment: The answer there also answers this question, so I believe this counts as a duplicate.